# Crossplatform overriding of TypeScript config for gulp delegated to ts-node

Tags: typescript, gulp, ts-node

I know what **ts-node** does not support ECMAScript modules, but I need them, not CommonJS for my project:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "ES2020",
  "module": "ESNext",
  // ...
}
```

If run `gulp taskName`, error

```
[11:27:19] Requiring external module ts-node/register
D:\IntelliJ IDEA\RequestedClientProjects\XXXXX\gulpfile.ts:1
import Gulp from "gulp";
```

will occur. I know what all I need to do is specify `"target": "CommonJS"` in TypeScript configuration, but as I said above, `ES2020` are required mainly for my project. How to override the TSConfig just for gulp?

I tried:

- `gulp taskName --compiler-options={"module":"commonJS"}` - nothing changed
- `"TS_NODE_PROJECT='./tsconfig.cjs.json'; gulp taskName` - got `TS_NODE_PROJECT not found` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using ts-node to run your app, which is most likely the case as you are using Gulp, you could add a "ts-node" section to your tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "module": "es2020",
    ...
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs"
    }
  }
```